# regex to match a word and ignore the line if it contains another word

Tags: regex

needs to match the lines with [m] and ignore the lines with [F]

regex needs to select lines 1& 2 only

`1.[m]dfsd`
 `2.[M]`
 `3.[M]dfdfd[F]`
 `4.[M]dfsd[f]`
 `5.[m]dfd[F]`
 `6.[m]fsdf[f]`

tried this 
(?=.*[m])(?!=.*[f])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to use lookaheads is on the right track.  I would use a negative lookahead to exclude `[F]`, and then match `[m]` anywhere in the pattern:

```
^(?!.*\[[Ff]\]).*\[[Mm]\].*$
```

### Demo

Note that I used `[Mm]` and `[Ff]` to match male and female as case insensitive.

Comment: perfect. Thank you!